# REGEX help to detect urls with format http://t.co/foo

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I am trying to match shortened URLs using the built-in regex capabilities of ActionScript 3.

I'm currently using:

```
_urlRegex:RegExp = /[^"|^>](https?:\/\/+[\S]*)/gi;
```

But the following url is not detected:

```
var errStr:String="http://t.co/foo";

var clean:String= errStr.replace(_urlRegex, "")
trace (clean);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace it by:

```
_urlRegex:RegExp = /[^">](https?:\/\/\S*)/gi
```

the `+` is not needed here since it means 1 or more times.

Note that `[^"|^>]` is seen as character class that exclude : `"`, `|`, `^`, `>`

Keep in mind that a character class is only a list of characters and that symbols as `|` are seen as literal inside it.

Comment: I came across this post http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls but don't know how to properly convert the example so it works in Flash. Tried escaping the forward slashes but still get errors